# Why is the refractive index $n$ linked to the wavevector $\hat{n}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

Preamble: I'm studying light-light scattering in Effective QED but I notice that I don't remember a single thing from my EM/Optics courses so I decided to review some things.

Question: **why is the refractive index $n$ linked to the wavevector $\hat{n}$?**
Explaination: I'm having trouble linking my knowledge of relativistic EM and classic Optics.
From Relativistic EM I know that
$$k^\mu=(\omega,\vec{k})=(\omega,k\hat{n})$$
where $k^\mu$ is the wavevector, $\omega$ is the frequency/energy, $k=2\pi/\lambda$ is the wavenumber, and $\hat{n}$ is simply the direction of the wave(tri)vector. This is true in general, and in particular for light in a vacuum $k=\omega$.
From Optics I know that
$$c=nv_p=n\frac{\omega}{k}$$
where (again) $\omega$ is the frequency/energy, $k=2\pi/\lambda$ is the wavenumber, and $n$ is the refractive index.

**Why does $n^2$=$\hat{n}^2$?**
The trouble comes from the fact that, in my Effective QED calculations, I have to prove that $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}k^\mu k_\mu=-\omega^2Q^2<0$ where $F^{\mu\nu}$ is a background field, $k^\mu$ is the wavevector of the incident wave, and $Q^2$ is a generic (positive) factor. To expand $F$ we used $F^2=2\left(\vec{B}^2-\vec{E}^2\right)=2\vec{E}^2(n^2-1)$ while to expand $k$ we used $k^2=-\omega^2(\hat{n}^2-1)$, ultimately factoring $(n^2-1)^2$. Why did we do this?

Comment: Surely, if $\hat{n}$ is defined to be a unit vector then $\hat{n}^2 = 1$? Are you sure that it is $\hat{n}$ appearing in your last paragraph? It looks to me like what is happening is $k^\mu k_\mu = \omega^2 -k^2 = \omega^2(1-n^2)$ where the last line has used the definition of refractive index?

Comment: @BySymmetry yes, I have just realized that. I'll delete the question.